# Are the categories $U(\mathfrak{g})$-$\mathrm{mod}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathrm{rep}$ equivalent?

Tags: category-theory, modules, representation-theory, lie-algebras, universal-property

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra. Denote by $U(\mathfrak{g})$ its universal enveloping algebra.
Let $U(\mathfrak{g})$-$\mathrm{mod}$ be the category of modules over $U(\mathfrak{g})$, and $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathrm{rep}$ be the category of $\mathfrak{g}$-representations.

Are the categories $U(\mathfrak{g})$-$\mathrm{mod}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$-$\mathrm{rep}$ equivalent?

Comment: Since $U(\mathfrak{g})$-modules are the same as $U(\mathfrak{g})$-representation, it is enough show that $U(\mathfrak{g})$-representations are in bijection with $\mathfrak{g}$-representations (morphism will be in bijection thanks to the universal property of the quotient).

Comment: What is your background knowledge? What have you tried? (Also, I assume the Lie algebra is defined over some field $k$, and "representations" means over that same field?)